# LINQ where clause condition in if

Tags: c#, linq, collections, where-clause

I have a class containing following properties:

```
public class Suborder
{
     public List<OrderLineItem> OrderLineItemList { get; set; }
     public string ProviderCode { get; set; }
}


public class OrderLineItem
{
    public List<OrderLineItem> BundleComponentList { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

I want to traverse through BundleComponentList to check if its any of its item has Product value equal to Shoes. I tried like this but getting error

```
if (suborder.OrderLineItemList.Any(x => x.Product == "Shoes") || suborder.OrderLineItemList.Where(x=>x.BundleComponentList.Any(y=>y.Product == "Shoes")))
```

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

What is wrong with my LINQ?

Comment: Just change your where to Any suborder.OrderLineItemList.Any(x=>x.BundleComponentList.Any(y=>y.Product == "Shoes"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `Where` as `Where` returns a sequence, not a `bool`.

```
suborder.OrderLineItemList.Any(x => x.BundleComponentList.Any(y => y.Product == "Shoes")))
```

Comment: I have a confusion that will `Any` traverse through all the BundleComponentList items or will it just pick the one with Product == "Shoes"?

Comment: @HumaAli `Any` as the name states will stop as soon as "any item passes the condition" and return true, but if there's no match it will traverse the entire sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`Where()` does not return a boolean value but an `IEnumerable` and so it cannot be used in an if-clause. You should use `Any()` in your case.

```
if (suborder.OrderLineItemList.Any(x => x.Product == "Shoes") || 
    suborder.OrderLineItemList.Any(x => x.BundleComponentList.Any(y => y.Product == "Shoes")))
```

Please also note that the above if-clause assumes that suborder is never null.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine lambda with LINQ for it. Much easier to read and see what's going on:

```
var orders = from o in suborder.OrderLineItemList
             where
               o.Product == "Shoes" ||
               o.BundleComponentList.Any(c => c.Product == "Shoes")
             select o;

bool isShoesOrder = orders.Any();
```